# Delete a row from hierarchical datatable with all related child (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, dataset, hierarchical-data

I have a table in SQL with hierarchical structure like this:

```
IDBudjet    ParentID    Header
1           NULL        Projects
2           1           Project A
3           1           Project B
4           1           Project C
5           2           Overhead
6           5           salary
```

and this table defined in vb.net DataSet like attached picture.

[image: My DataSet]

My Problem:
Logically I expect when a row deleted in DataTable all related child rows deleted too in any level, but this error rised:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_Budjet_Budjet". The conflict occurred in database "SapCord", table "dbo.Budjet", column 'ParentID'

Would you please help me.

Comment: Working as intended most likely. You have to delete the referenced record first. The foreign key is (usually) there to prevent orphaned records. If you delete the project before the budget then the budget will be "wrong", correct?

Comment: I don't know what happened exactly. My table has self joint. therefore i expect when a record deleted then all related child also deleted.

Comment: That depends on how the key is configured in the table.